# How to add a link in Xcode comment to open another source code file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

I'm wondering if its possible to add a link (hyperlink) in a comment to open another source code file (in the same project) or a specific method in another class in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little cheat to use links `#pragma YourClass.m`

**UPDATE:** Using inside comment    `//<YourClass>`

To Access a method use `// <yourMethodName>`  your method name need not to be of same class. you can have a cross class reference as well. currently it works for method without parameters only

**NOTE:** in comment don't include fileExtension like .h or .m

Comment: Thanks, but it can't be used inside a comment, I need something inside comment to be used

Comment: Great thanks a lot, BTW is there a way to open a specific method in a class :) . I tried <Class:viewDidLoad> but it doesn't work

Comment: @HossamGhareeb answer is updated for methods having no parameters